# hierarchical clustering with gower distance - hclust() and philentropy::distance()

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I've got a mixed data set (categorical and continuous variables) and I'd like to do **hierarchical clustering** using Gower distance.

I base my code on an example from https://www.r-bloggers.com/hierarchical-clustering-in-r-2/, which uses base R `dist()` for Euclidean distance. Since `dist()` doesn't compute Gower distance, I've tried using `philentropy::distance()` to compute it but it doesn't work.

Thanks for any help!

```
# Data
data("mtcars")
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

# Hierarchical clustering with Euclidean distance - works 
clusters <- hclust(dist(mtcars[, 1:2]))
plot(clusters)

# Hierarchical clustering with Gower distance - doesn't work
library(philentropy)
clusters <- hclust(distance(mtcars[, 1:2], method = "gower"))
plot(clusters)
```

Comment: The `philentropy::distance` function returns a matrix, try converting it to a `dist` object with `as.dist` before clustering

Comment: I tried clusters <- hclust(as.dist(distance(mtcars[, 1:2], method = "gower"))), and it still gives me Error in DistMatrixWithoutUnitMAT(x, gower, test.na) : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the `distance` function itself.

I don't know if it's intentional or not, but the current implementation of `philentropy::distance` with the "gower" method cannot handle any mixed data types, since the first operation is to transpose the data.frame, producing a character matrix which then throws the typing error when passed to the `DistMatrixWithoutUnit` function.

You might try using the `daisy` function from `cluster` instead.

```
library(cluster)

x <- mtcars[,1:2]

x$cyl <- as.factor(x$cyl)

dist <- daisy(x, metric = "gower")

cls <- hclust(dist)

plot(cls)
```

**EDIT:** For future reference it seems like `philentropy` will be updated to included better type handling in the next version. From the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/philentropy/vignettes/Distances.html)

> In future versions of philentropy I will optimize the  distance()
>   function so that internal checks for data type correctness and correct
>   input data will take less termination time than the base dist()
>   function.

Answer (score 0):

LLL;
Sorry, I don't know English and I can't explain. Now this is a try. 
But the code is good ;-)

```
library(philentropy)
clusters <- hclust(
                   as.dist(
                          distance(mtcars[, 1:2], method = "gower")))
plot(clusters)
```

Good look

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty efficiently with the `gower` package

```
library(gower)

d <- sapply(1:nrow(mtcars), function(i) gower_dist(mtcars[i,],mtcars))
d <- as.dist(d)
h <- hclust(d)
plot(h)
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for this great question and thanks to all of you who provided excellent answers.

Just to resolve the issue for future readers:

```
# import example data
data("mtcars")
# store example subset with correct data type 
mtcars_subset <- tibble::tibble(mpg = as.numeric(as.vector(mtcars$mpg)), 
                                cyl = as.numeric(as.vector(mtcars$cyl)), 
                                disp = as.numeric(as.vector(mtcars$disp)))

# transpose data.frame to be conform with philentropy input format
mtcars_subset <- t(mtcars_subset)

# cluster
clusters <- hclust(as.dist(philentropy::distance(mtcars_subset, method = "gower")))
plot(clusters)

# When using the developer version on GitHub you can also specify 'use.row.names = TRUE'
clusters <- hclust(as.dist(philentropy::distance(mtcars_subset, method = "gower", 
use.row.names = TRUE)))
plot(clusters)
```

As you can see, clustering works perfectly fine now.

The problem is that in the example dataset the column `cyl` stores `factor` values and not `double` values as is required for the `philentropy::distance()` function. Since the underlying code is written in `Rcpp`, non-conform data types will cause problems. As noted correctly by Esther, I will implement a better way to check type safety in future versions of the package.

```
head(tibble::as.tibble(mtcars))

# A tibble: 6 x 11
mpg cyl    disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
<dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  21   6       160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
2  21   6       160   110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
3  22.8 4       108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
4  21.4 6       258   110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
5  18.7 8       360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
6  18.1 6       225   105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
```

To overcome this limitation, I stored the columns of interest from the `mtcars` dataset in a separate data.frame/tibble and converted all columns to double values via `as.numeric(as.vector(mtcars$mpg))`.

The resulting subset data.frame now stores only `double` values as required.

```
mtcars_subset

# A tibble: 32 x 3
 mpg   cyl  disp
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  21       6  160 
2  21       6  160 
3  22.8     4  108 
4  21.4     6  258 
5  18.7     8  360 
6  18.1     6  225 
7  14.3     8  360 
8  24.4     4  147.
9  22.8     4  141.
10  19.2     6  168.
# … with 22 more rows
```

Please also note that if you provide the `philentropy::distance()` function only 2 input vectors, then only one distance value will be returned and the `hclust()` function won't be able to compute any clusters with one value. Hence, I added a third column `disp` to enable visualization of the clusters.

I hope this helps.